# C++ functions different format

Tags: c++, function

When you declare a method in C++ do you do it for example as below (if the class name is Lexer for example):

```
bool Lexer :: IsDigit()
{
 //code
}
```

or

```
bool isDigit()
{
 //code
}
```

since I am used with the first style however I am finding the last one as well such as in this site: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Comment: Are you confusing declaration, definition and inline definition?

Comment: Nah. He just has no clue about free functions, my guess

Comment: Are you coming from Java? C++ has both (free) functions and methods.

Comment: Those are definitions, not declarations. If you read the text in that tutorial, you'll probably notice that it makes no mention of classes or methods (or member functions, as methods are usually called in C++). There's a reason for that. I suggest you get a good book.

Answer (score 2):

Either like this:

```
struct Lexer
{
    bool IsDigit() { return true; }
    // ...
};
```

Or like this:

```
struct Lexer
{
    bool IsDigit();
    // ...
};

bool Lexer::IsDigit() { return true; }
```

The first version includes the member function definition inside the class definition. The latter only puts the member function declaration inside the class definition, but leaves the member function definition outside (or "out of line").

Answer (score 0):

The second example is either

a) a free standing function or
 b) an inline method definition (if it's inside a class body).

The first example is an external method definition.

```
class Lexer {
    bool IsDigit(); // method declaration
}
bool Lexer :: IsDigit() { return false; } // method definition

bool IsDigit() { return false; } // free-standing function 

class Lexer2{
    bool IsDigit { return false; } // inline method definition
}
```

They can be called like so:

```
Lexer l;
l.isDigit(); // calls the first method
isDigit(); // calls the free-standing function
Lexer2 l2;
l2.IsDigit(); // calls the latter method
```

Comment: May the downvoter explain why?

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? I deliberately left out the return statements because that's not what this answer is about. If you think they're vital in the context of the question just edit them in. Or you mean because it's private?

Comment: This is not an SSCCE, this is *only* meant to show the "formats" of functions as asked in the question.

Comment: By the way, the code compiles fine with any major compiler with `-Wno-return-type`, where a bool function without explicit return statement yields false.

Comment: I'm not arguing because of the internet points, but because I think it's unnecessary to complain about something the answer is clearly not about. As I said, if you think it's vital, just edit it in. That's why everyone can edit answers.

Comment: The fact that you are stalking this answer and adding your opinion repeatedly even hours after our discussion is pathetic. How about you just calm down? You have all the option to change or flag it if it bothers you that much. My answer helped the questioner with his uncertainty about function definitions and that's all I intended.

Comment: I'm certainly not _'stalking'_ this answer! You've been asking for clarification on the downvote, and I gave you more than any user can expect about downvotes at all. So again, what **you're bothering** about (it's not me!)? Told you about your options as well ... Edited as requested though now ... Kerrek's answer had this from the first post, and I preferred this ...